# Clojure Map 2 Elem Code Golf

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I have:

(map (fn [k v] [k v])
  lst1
  lst2)

Now, it just seems like there should be a shorter way to write this. How can I make it shorter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(map vector lst1 lst2)
```

(Has the added bonus of working for any number of lists)

Comment: lol; too amazintly obvious in hind sight -- is this why clojure doesn't need haskell's zip?

Comment: @user1311390, yep, I guess so, but strictly Haskell doesn't need `zip` either, since `zip == zipWith (,)`. If you want to be able to use `zip` in Clojure you can easily define it: `(defn zip [ & args ] (apply (partial map vector) args))`.

Comment: Wat, why is there a `partial` involved? That's equivalent to just `(apply map vector args)`.

Comment: @amalloy, yep that works too... I was transliterating Haskell to Clojure.